# CSS in IE doesn't work on server - but works on Localhost?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have encountered a really strange problem. I've designed a site almost completely in CSS3 and uploaded it to the server, just to be shocked to find out that almost no features are supported by IE8 and the site layout is completely unrecognizable.

But then there was even stranger thing to it: IE8 displays the site properly, when on localhost? Has anyone encountered a situation like that? What could cause it, because, apparently, it's not that CSS3 properties are not supported on IE but something with the settings of the server?

The site is: http://solnajeskynepraha.cz

How does it work for you if you view it in IE?

Thanks for feedback in advance

Comment: you html source code starts with <?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html>.... keep only <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: add </body></html> at end of page

Comment: Your server is failing to parse the PHP.

Comment: You also have invalid HTML:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsolnajeskynepraha.cz&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected all the errors. Now it is parsed properly, I just happened to forget to remove the old XHTML Doctype. While Chrome just ignores it, IE stumbles.

Comment: @AlgonJaner It's not a good thing when browsers ignore doctypes. You want the browser to respect them. That being said, you should be using the `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype unless you have a specific reason not to. That being said, the site appears to work properly - did the above comments resolve the issue for you? It sounds like your site was falling back into Quirks Mode on account of invalid markup.

Answer (score 0):

[Validation for solnajeskynepaha.cz landing page](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//solnajeskynepraha.cz/)

still 7 errors...

f12>Console tab, then refresh your page...to show any suppressed error messages.

CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.
File: opensans.ttf

Check your IE Accessibility settings... Internet Options>General tab>Accessibility button and Fonts button...

Configure your browser test suite to use the same default fonts.... and font size (View>Text Size>Medium)

Ensure your domain is mapping to the Internet Zone (file>Properties menu) and that you have configured IE Security zone settings to the default (Security tab of Internet Options>click "Reset all zones to default".

Regards.